# How to add Validation pattern not to allow only space in input Angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I used formBuilder in Angular2 and want to add validation pattern for not to allow "only spaces" in input.

Comment: Guys, if you wanna downvote and not explain why go on youtube plz

Comment: @theFreedomBanana Isn't that obvious? At OP: What have you tried? Show us some code. Why / how did it fail? Was there an error message? Show us an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the whole problem.

Comment: @TobiMcNamodi I don't really see the need for code or an example, the title is pretty self-explanatory. And even though, the OP seems fresh new on S.O, probably not aware of all the discipline some of us requires, and downvoting without a comment will not enlight her

Answer (score 15):

Use the following:

```
Validators.pattern(/^\S*$/)
```

### [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/venW77jW9yoADfwIAYyg?p=preview)

Comment: For me it only worked when I used lower case "S" i.e --->  Validators.pattern(/^\s*$/)

Answer (score 12):

space Not allowed

```
let nospacePattern = [a-zA-Z0-9]
```

## Update

As per requirement in comment section.

> need pattern not to allow only spaces. (space in between words are allowed).but when user enter spaces in input and try to save it then it should not allow to save

```
Validators.pattern(".*\\S.*[a-zA-z0-9 ]");
```

## Update 2

Better and Cleaner way to use custom validation pattern like below -

```
controlName: ['', [Validators.required, this.noWhitespaceValidator]],

....
....
noWhitespaceValidator(control: FormControl) {
    const isWhitespace = (control && control.value && control.value.toString() || '').trim().length === 0;
    const isValid = !isWhitespace;
    return isValid ? null : { 'whitespace': true };
  }
```

Comment: need pattern not to allow only spaces. (space in between words are allowed).but when user enter spaces in input and try to save it then  it should not allow to save.

Comment: @PoonamThote check the Update please

Comment: Update 2 works perfectly to use in validation service. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

try this, it will return false while sapce key press :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
       <input class="form-control" type="number" formControlName="pinCode" placeholder="Pin Code"
             (keydown.space)="$event.preventDefault()">
    </div>
  `,
  providers: [myService]
})
```

visit for more Events :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: This will work only for user pressing the space key, if they copy/paste a text with a space in between two words, the field will allow this anyway

Comment: This won't work if you want to enter a value like e.g. `John Doe`. You can't add the empty space after first name. Also the question says to prevent adding `ONLY` empty space, not preventing adding a space between words.

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced same issue on which I have tried following code and it works.

As per my requirement, in form comment box should be has min 30 character and that character should be non-space.so to add validation I have used following code. I am using reactive forms. In ts file, add following code

```
comment:[''[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(30),Validators.pattern(/^((?!\s{2,}).)*$/)]]
```

`Hey this sentence has one space between every word` //this will work

`Hey this   sentence   has more than one space between every word` //this will throw err

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using a custom Validator:

```
export class SharedCustomValidators {
  static spaceOnlyValidator(
    control: AbstractControl
  ): { [key: string]: any } | null {
    const isSpace = /^\s+$/.test(control.value);
    if (control.value && isSpace) {
      return { isOnlyWhiteSpace: true };
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
businessName: [
   '',
   [Validators.required, SharedCustomValidators.spaceOnlyValidator],
],
```

Explanation

- The regex /^\s+$/ is used to check if the value is space only
- If it is space only an error isOnlyWhiteSpace, is returned in the control's errors object

Advantages

- Reusable
- Custom error code

Bonus

- You can add as many validators as you want on that class