# pattern in angular 2 that not allow only spaces and any special characters, it should allow characters,numbers, underscore and hypen

Tags: angular

I need validator that allow only characters,numbers, underscore and hypen. if user enter only spaces then disabled save button in angular 2 FormBuilder validators.pattern(). I already tried 
`Validators.pattern(".*\\S.*") and Validators.pattern(".*\\S.*[a-zA-z0-9 ]")` but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
Validators.pattern(".*\\S.*[a-zA-z0-9_-]")
```

<kbd>[Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HKeVKgH3Hi8MYbcdin80?p=preview)</kbd>

see also

- [How to add Validation pattern not to allow only space in input Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42994241/5043867)

Comment: as per working demo if we enter combination of special character and alphabets then its not working properly.

Comment: for eg. if enter abc%k like this then its not working.

Comment: opps i did't see special symbol in your question, btw good question